# How do I set a TextView to a Long Value?

Tags: java, android, variables

I'm trying to create a countdown timer for a reaction android app that I'm making (just to learn about threads and stuff), and am having trouble with the initial 3,2,1 portion of the code I'm creating.

```
long gameStart, elapsed, cdElapsed, countdownStart, cdDisplay;
TextView timerDisplayBottom, timerDisplayTop;

private void countdown() {
    for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        timerDisplayBottom.setText(cdDisplay);
        timerDisplayTop.setText(cdDisplay);
        cdElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        cdElapsed = (countdownStart - cdElapsed);
        cdDisplay = (3 - cdElapsed);
    }

}
```

I need to set the text of the timerDisplayBottom and Top to the number that cdDisplay generates.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Some feedback would be nice. Did you try my solution (I demonstrated with 1 TextView, you will have to repeat for every other textview if you're printing a `long`)?

Comment: Yes, sorry I thought I marked your answer as correct yesterday, my mistake :3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should probably use `String.valueOf()` so you get a String representation of the `long`

```
timerDisplayTop.setText(String.valueOf(cdDisplay));
```